# walk the Model3DGroup tree

Tags: wpf, 3d, visual-tree

I have a complex 3D scene consisting of Model3DGroups that I need to analyze at runtime. Since `Model3D` nodes do not participate neither in the VisualTree nor in the LogicalTree is there any other way I can find the parent of a `Model3DGroup`?

Comment: I think I may need to know this too in the near future, so did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: You could try to start a bounty.

Comment: You can't walk the tree upside, but you can walk from root(you have to remember it) downside and compare children and content properties with searched value.